# Partial modifier change of tuple type

Tags: typescript

Assuming some types `A` and `B`, how can i change the type `[A?, B?]` to `[A, B?]`, as in make only part of the indices required, e.g. the first?

Note that i took the simplest example displaying the issue. While i don't think there is any trick for "just two elements", i'll state, that finally the intention is to turn up to the first 32 elements of any given tuple type to non-optional, but leave the (potentially) remaining as-is.

From what i know, homomorphic mapped types don't support doing this in one go, and intersection breaks tuple types. Detection for `undefined` in the related type does not accurately represent being optional.

---

More info for the interested:

Refer to [definitely-assigned-for-destructuring-with-nouncheckedindexedaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423459/12435589) for the helper function to improve, [index-structure-of-open-ended-tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482434/index-structure-of-open-ended-tuples) for details about specialties with tuple-types.

In case the helper function is called with a non-deformed tuple type, it's desirable to keep the tuple structure in tact. This seems possible by not mapping, but reconstructing a new tuple type from the old (preliminary test, `32` potentially a parameter later. *edit*: the current version in [definitely-assigned-for-destructuring-with-nouncheckedindexedaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423459/12435589) now should show the problem in a properly working fashion):

```
type TupleRestReconstructor<T extends readonly any[], Head extends readonly any[] = []> = Head['length'] extends 32
  ? [...Head, ...T]
  : T extends [infer First, ...infer Tail]
    ? TupleRestReconstructor<Tail, [...Head, First]>
    : TupleRestReconstructor<T, [...Head, T[0]]>;
```

This sadly breaks for inputs that include optional elements, e.g. `[boolean?, ...string[]]`, as optional elements have no inferrable concrete type. Luckily, the task is to assert elements as existent anyways, it's therefore possible to mark all elements in question (this means the first n, where n is potentially a parameter, undecided yet) as required. However, in case of asserting for `[string?, boolean?, number?]`, that the first two exist, the third should not switch to required.

Comment: Can you show more about what your case looks like?

Comment: @md2perpe added material on what this is for, and thoughts on the process.